# Exception: SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: User.Sales_Office__c in CPQ Quote document preview

Tags: cpq, quote-template

How do I get CPQ, as a managed package, to include certain custom fields in the data query that it performs as part of generating a quote document from an SBQQ_Quote object using a template?  My quote template includes custom merge fields from the salesRep (User) object.   I am getting the familiar error listed in the title.    I am executing this as as sysadmin.   thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have subsequently learnt that only a limited set of merge fields is supported for the salesRep and Contact records, as documented here.   Custom fields are not supported.

Reference:  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.cpq_merge_fields_pc_sr_supported.htm&type=5

For those with similar woes, you will have to create a formula field on SBQQ Quote in order to include other fields from these two records in your template.